# find the minimum distance fromapoint on x axis from 3 other points on x axis

Tags: python

I want to calculate the minimum distance from 3 points the user entered, all the points are on the x-axis, could anyone help me to fix my code, please?

```
d=[]
i=0
a=list(input("please enter x1, x2, x3: "))
a=a.sort()
for item in range(0,(max(a))):
    d=sum(a[i]-item)
print(f"here is the minimum distance{min(d)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

first `list(input(...))` probably isnt doing what you want
if i enter `'123 33 12'` this would become `['1','2','3',' ','3'...]`

instead you want split

```
a_list = input("Enter some numbers with spaces").split()
['123','33','12']
```

then you need to make them integers

```
num_list = [int(x) for x in a_list]
```

then you just get the min

```
closest = min(num_list,key=lambda x:abs(x-56))
print(f"{closest} is the closest point to 56")
```

if you only care about the distance and not the actual value just change where you cast it to int ot

```
dist_list = [abs(int(x)-56) for x in a_list]
print(f"minimum distance = {min(dist_list)}")
```

with your extra comment i guess its just

```
num_list = [11,55,27]
print("POINT:",sum(num_list)/len(num_list),f"requires the least movement for all {num_list}")
```

Comment: Thank you, how did you determine "56" is the closest point? cause it is asking for the closest point(minimum distance) to the user entering the 3 points?

Comment: do you mean if i have 3 points `[A, B, C]` I want to find the minimum of `A-B,A-C,B-C`?  56 is "item" in your original question

Comment: let me explain more, I mean I have 3 points(as 3 people in different spots on an x-axil) [A, B, C] and, they want to meet each other on a point that the sum of the distances from that point is minimum. Basically, I want to calculate the distance of the closest point to all 3 people.

Comment: ahhh that makes much more sense ... but its just going to be `average([A,B,C])`  ...

Comment: I am not sure if it is the average because the example given to us is [6,9,10] and the number 4 is the point that others have a minimum sum of the distance from this point.

Comment: how is 4 the nearest? 10 has to go 6, 9 has to go 5, 6 has to go 2 =13 total moves, if its at 8 then 9 goes 1, 10 goes 2 and 6 goes 2, which is only 5 movements...

Comment: Are you sure you need the minimum distance? Because 4 is the maximum distance between points  [6,9,10].

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is doing what you expect.
The question isn't quiet clear to me, or maybe the loop you use just confuses me.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input("Please enter x-coordinates separated by spaces: ").split()
    a = [int(c) for c in a]
    a.sort()
    best = float('inf')
    for i, number in enumerate(a[1:]):
        best = min(best, number-a[i])
        
    print(f"The minimum distance of the given points is {best}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
print('how many numbers?')
n = int(input('n: '))

a = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    x = input(f'x_{i}: ')
    a.append(x)

a_int = sorted([int(x) for x in a])
print(a_int)

rest = []
for j in range(n-1):
    r = abs(a_int[j] - a_int[j+1])
    rest.append((r, j))

p = min(rest)

print(f'closest points are ({a_int[p[1]]}, {a_int[p[1]+1]}) and distance is {p[0]}')
```

you will have the chance to input how many numbers you want to check, later on, it is going to sort them from the smallest to the biggest. To check the distance, it will rest each one of them and save the position to later search for the minimum.

let me know if does it help. it is a bit of brute force though ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use @Joran Beasley input function

```
a_list = input("Enter some numbers with spaces").split()
```

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

# convert strings to floats of integers
a = np.array(a).astype(float)

# find distances between each point
distances = np.abs(np.subtract(a, a[:,np.newaxis]))

# remove same point distances (distance = 0)
distances_non_zero = distances[distances != 0]

# get minimum distance
minimum_distace = np.min(distances_non_zero)
```